# Monero Wallet on encrypted USB stick?

Tags: encryption

Is it possible to install Monero Wallet on an external hard drive (128GB USB stick) that is actually encrypted with Windows bitlocker?
Would it work properly as same as if the Monero wallet was installed on a non-encrypted USB stick?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you will store only wallet file you only need a few MB storage, also wallet files are already encrypted with password.